# Add a tag for scientific names

Tags: feature-request, tags

A tag for scientific names would be helpful. It would be appropriate for the first question I asked here. Please add it?

Comment: Tags can be added by anyone with >150 rep. Not sure I see a need for this particular tag, but if you do want to advocate for one I'd suggest including a collection of several questions, with links, where you think that tag would be helpful. Remember that tags aren't good for making things on-topic but are mostly so that people with relevant expertise can follow a subject and easily track posts on that subject (including getting alerts when questions are posted). Probably [tag:species-identification] covers a lot of these.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a tag for [nomenclature](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature) which should cover your needs. This is meant to be used for:

> The principles, conventions, and terms used to systematically classify biological information, entities, processes, but also subfields of biology.

Several Qs on species names are also already tagged by this tag. Or is there a specific reason why you think this is insufficient?